Why get this P=NP? What I am doing wrong?
As we know, all NP problems are decidable because there is a NTM that can solve them in polynomial time. To my knowledge, any NTM is equivalent to a DTM. Thus, if NP problems can be decided by a NTM e.g. M, there is a DTM N equivalent to M that can solve this NP problem. But this should means that P=NP which is still an open problem. Surely, I did something wrong here. But do not know where.
Can anyone explain where I am doing wrong?

Both $\texttt{P}$ and $\texttt{NP}$ are subsets of the recursive function $\texttt{R}$, so by definition all $\texttt{NP}$ problems must be decidable by DTMs.
But that doesn't make them equal.
The difference lies in the second point you brought up, the definitions are
$$\texttt{P} = \{L : L \text{ is decidable by a polynomial time DTM}\}$$
and
$$\texttt{NP} = \{L : L \text{ is decidable by a polynomial time NTM}\}.$$
It's easy to see that $\texttt{P} \subseteq \texttt{NP}$, but $\texttt{P} \overset{?}{\supseteq} \texttt{NP}$ is an open question as of yet.

So, to make it clear to myself, solvable means decidable and conversely, decidable means solvable. It is right?

And also, you mean that DTM can solve any problem that a NTM can do, but this does not mean that it can do it in polynimial time? I mean, there maybe cases that NTM can solve a problem it in polynimoial time. And a DTM can also solve it but not in polynomial time. Is it what you are saying?

To my knowledge people usually say that a decision problem is solvable, and that a language is decidable.

Yes, whether or not such a problem exists is an open question.
